# How to convert Flutter package to JavaScript

Tags: flutter-web, dart2js

Whether it is possible to convert the entire Flutter package to JavaScript or else how to convert a single dart file to a JavaScript file. If I try to convert a single dart file to a JavaScript file using **dart2js**, it is failed like the main method is not found. Any idea to convert the single dart file without the main method.